# Modelling a Dagger (1): How to bend straight faces

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model this dagger I found on the internet ([source](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Dagger)):
[image: dagger]

So I first concentrated in the top part (the blade itself), and later model the handle. I started out with a cube, and tweaked it until I got to this point:

[image: dagger-1]

Now you can see my problem: I have no idea about how to "round" the sides of the blade, so that they are not straight but with a certain curvature.

I tried adding a bezier curve that adjusted to the outline of the blade, and then added a Curve modifier, but it seemed to bend only one part of the blade.

Of course I could just Loop Cut and Slide, and scale it up a bit. However I'm looking for a more precise way to do it. I'm pretty new to Blender and any advice on how to model the blade is more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be in Edit Mode add a loop cut in the middle CTRL+R and delete the vertices on one side so you are working with half of the blade.

[image: Delete Half]

Add a Mirror Modifier and check "Clipping".

[image: Add Mirror Modifier]

Add some loop cuts from top to bottom CTRL+R and scroll the mouse wheel to increase the number of loop cuts then Right Mouse click to complete. I used 12 in this example.

[image: 12 Loop Cuts]

Select "Proportional Editing" and a "Fall Off Type". I choose Spherical. Select vertices in the middle and press "G" and use the mouse wheel to determine how many neighboring vertices are affected (Illustrated by a circle in the viewport)as you drag. Right mouse click to complete.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In blender there is 2 possibilities to make a curve :
- Bezier curve (that is a real curve since you can see the "round" to any scale, there is no point).
- A line (that is a finite number of point), that will seems "round" in zom out but that you will see the edge is zoom in.

Note : you can use bezier curve at first and then transform is in a line with point.

In your case (that is beginner modeling) the best is loop cut.
I advised you to read some car modeling tutorial, you will understand how to model complex objects that have straigt line combines with curves.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking but if you are trying to put a split down the middle and the move it out so it bends the flat face. CTRL+r will let you do a loop cut and you can do this down the center of the mesh.

[image]

If this isn't exactly what you are looking for then please explain alittle more and I will be happy to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop cut and slide tool (found in the tools tab in edit mode) to add more polygons to your mesh and them move them into a more rounded shape, curves can't really be used as edges in 3d programs (as far as I know) so the rounded edge of the dagger that you're copying is just small straight lines arranged into a curve